# Uncomfirmed Transaction

Tags: wallet-security

I sent 2.1439245 bitcoins to 
1AEcB37MngXzuvailFr1f31qobvzBFXF4e9
on May 27 and the transaction has still not been received. I contacted the merchant that I bought from and they said that they have not received any bitcoins and I should claim for a refund. 
The transaction number is 
6ff626d639d4fb9658ecaff

Comment: https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC neither of those numbers seem to be valid. What wallet are you using?

Comment: From whom would you claim a refund?  To me it sounds like you still have the bitcoin in question, so I'm not sure what needs to be refunded.  Since the address you listed is invalid, you couldn't have possibly submitted a transaction to the network paying that address.  Ask the merchant to give you a valid address, or you won't be able to pay them.

Comment: Before you send Bitcoin next time look up the receiving address in a block explorer to see if it is valid. Re-sync your wallet. Your Bitcoin is still there. You cannot lost Bitcoin by sending it to an invalid address.

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, neither the address nor the transaction id are valid. Therefore, you have not sent any bitcoin when using that address, except if you wallet is really poorly made.

It might, however, be the case that you wallet doesn't show you the funds any more if you tried to send them. In this case, export your private key and create a new wallet using it. The new wallet will show you your funds and you'll be able to send them to a correct address.