# Bitcoin did not get to reciever

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, address, network

I sent $50 worth of bitcoin to my cousins blockchain bitcoin address, it said sent and the bitcoin amount deducted from my wallet.  However, the bitcoin did not reflect in my cousin's wallet.  I checked the Transaction ID and it was there showing the transaction and amount sent. Till date my cousin did not receive the bitcoin.  What should I do to get back my bitcoin.

Comment: Hello eddychis, what wallet software did you use and did you check that your cousin's address matched the one in the transaction? We could take a look if you linked the transaction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncomfirmed Transaction](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44532/uncomfirmed-transaction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)